# How was Moshe Rabbeinu buried?

Tags: death, moshe-rabbeinu, parashat-vezot-habracha

This website (thetorah.com) raises some points about Moshe Rabbeinu's death.

https://www.thetorah.com/article/moshe-rabbeinu-never-died-the-hidden-ending

A few points that they make is:

1. If Moses ascends Mount Nebo in verse 1, how does he end up buried in the valley below in verse 6?
2. Where precisely does he meet his demise—on the mountain, in the valley, or somewhere in-between?
3. How is he transported to his final repose, and by whom?
4. Who is the unnamed “he” that buries Moses in verse 6?

Comment: rashi answers the last question "The Holy One, blessed be He, in His glory, buried him (Sotah 14a). R. Ishmael, however, said, It means: “He buried himself”." The Ibn Ezra answers the first "Mount Avarim (also known as Mount Nebo, named for a star) is the same place as the Gai which is at the top of the cliff across from Beth-Peor."

Comment: God himself buried him as it is written in Deuterenomy 34:12

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Possibly on verse 1 Moses sees the promised land, but it's not that he is buired there, as described on verse 6
2. The [Sefri](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%99_%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%93%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%9C%D7%93_%D7%95) addresses this question. It says the the location of the grave was miraculously unreachable, is you were on the top of the mountain. it looked like it's in the valley, but if you were in the valley it looked like it was on the top. If you don't want this explanation, you can explain that the view-point was on the mountain, and the burial was in the valley.
3. As @rosends says, It's either God who buried Moses, or he buried himself...
4. and the Rabbies who argue over it, are disagree about who is "he" in the verse.

Answer (score 0):

The slope of Mount Nebo could have been one of the walls of the valley.

One can be on the mountain and in the valley if he is standing on the slope of the mountain.

Notice that there are two words for valley: Emek and Gei.

Perhaps Emek is reserved for when there is a plateau at the bottom  (scroll down)

https://www.earthtrekkers.com/2-days-in-death-valley-itinerary/

And Gei is reserved for when the [mountains are so close together that as soon as you get to the bottom of one, you are ascending another](https://www.google.com/maps/@31.7713108,35.1757584,3a,75y,324.78h,82.28t/data=!3m8!1e1!3m6!1sAF1QipM3ue5V-WWW-_5scFxksZHYsrmwri82KaT6ySX4!2e10!3e11!6shttps:%2F%2Flh5.googleusercontent.com%2Fp%2FAF1QipM3ue5V-WWW-_5scFxksZHYsrmwri82KaT6ySX4%3Dw203-h100-k-no-pi-0-ya31.406992-ro-0-fo100!7i5660!8i2830).

If my distinction is correct, someone in a Gei will always be on a mountain and valley simultaneously.